# Is there a way for a discord.py bot to react to every reaction in an already reacted message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, lets say I want my bot to get a message, then when a random user reacts to that message, the bot adds the same reaction to that message, like for example when someone adds a reaction and I click on it to also react.

I know how to use message.add_reaction, but I cant find a way to do what I want, I dont know if there is a way to actually do it

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if "hi" in message.content:
        await message.add_reaction("(any reaction)")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an event called `on_reaction_add` in discord.py

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    if "hi" in message.content:
        await message.add_reaction(reaction)
```

Comment: Rather using `on_raw_reaction_add` because `on_reaction_add` is only called, when the message is found in the cache. And because messages are volatile, `on_raw_reaction_add` is better.